# Pass list view clicked value to another activity with shared preferences

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have three Activities.

I want to pass click data from the first activity to third activity.

First (click)>Second (Click) > Third

My problem is: within the `SwipeNavAdapter`

`String  data1 = sharedPreferences.getString(ListNavAdapter.ID_EXTRA, "")`  not showing the list from `ListNavAdapter`, but it shows list from `CourseAdapter`. I want to get clicked list item from the `ListNavAdapter` in the `SwipeNavAdapter`.

FIRST : ListNavAdapter

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SqliteDatabase.getInstance(this.getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT CHAPTER FROM BOOK GROUP BY CHAPTER order by _id", new String[]{});

 if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
 //
 } else {
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         listItem.add(cursor.getString(0));
     }
     arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
     listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 }
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
         String achal=(String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
         editor.putString(ID_EXTRA, achal);
         editor.apply();
         Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Course.class);
         intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(l));
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

Second : CourseAdapter

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
String  data = sharedPreferences.getString(ListNavAdapter.ID_EXTRA, "") ;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SqliteDatabase.getInstance(this.getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT TEXT_NO FROM BOOK WHERE CHAPTER='" + data + "' ORDER BY _id", new String[]{});

if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
   //
} else {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        listItem.add(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            String achal1=(String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(ID_EXTRAA, achal1);
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), SwipeNav.class);
            intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRAA, String.valueOf(l));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Third : SwipeNavAdapter

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String  data1 = sharedPreferences.getString(ListNavAdapter.ID_EXTRA, "") ;
    System.out.println(data1);
    ArrayList<String> listItem1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT TEXT FROM BOOK WHERE CHAPTER='" + data1 + "'", new String[]{});
    if (cursor1.getCount() == 0) {
        ///
    } else {
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
            listItem1.add(cursor1.getString(0));
        }
    }
    Object[] mStringArray1 = listItem1.toArray();
    Fragment fragment = new AFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    assert mStringArray1 != null;
    args.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT1, (String)mStringArray1[i]);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String  data1 = sharedPreferences.getString(ListNavAdapter.ID_EXTRA, "") ;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SqliteDatabase.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT TEXT FROM BOOK WHERE CHAPTER='" + data1 + "'", new String[]{});
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        listItem.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TEXT")));
    }
    return listItem.size();
}
```

Comment: @Naitik Soni, in Course Adapter ID_EXTRA shows right data from ListNavAdapter, In SwipeNavAdapter, ID_EXTRAA shows right data from CourseAdapter. But when I try to get ID_EXTRA in SwipeNavAdapter, it shows data of ID_EXTRAA means data from CourseAdapter not from ListNavAdapter

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is: within the SwipeNavAdapter
>
> String  data1 = sharedPreferences.getString(ListNavAdapter.ID_EXTRA,
>   "") not showing the list from ListNavAdapter, but it shows list from
>   CourseAdapter. I want to get clicked list item from the ListNavAdapter
>   in the SwipeNavAdapter.

I assume you are overriding the value in the `SharedPreferences` using the same key that has been used in `CourseAdapter` and `ListNavAdapter`. Make sure the keys `ID_EXTRA` in `ListNavAdapter` and `ID_EXTRAA` in `CourseAdapter` are different.

**The value will overwrite if you add the values under the same key for `sharedPreference`.**

Comment: Two keys are different

Comment: Can you provide all three files with code?? If still you are facing the problem.